# importing and validating data from excel using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, excel

I've been trying to import and validate excel data before entering into a DB using PHP. What the code should is load from excel and insert into a database after PHP validation such as checking email validation.If there is a problem it will display the error records in a table(with input boxes) with a div to the right telling the error. My Problem is it only shows the last record with error even though there is more than one error record. The second problem is the error message is not being displayed in the right div.

```
 $objPHPExcel=PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($uploadfile);
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) 
{

    $highestRow=$worksheet->getHighestRow();
    $nm = 1;
    $redo=0;
    for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow;$row++)
    {  


        $company_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$row)->getValue());
        $contact_person= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$row)->getValue());
        $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$row)->getValue());
        $location=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$row)->getValue());
        $type=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$row)->getValue());
        $sector=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,$row)->getValue());
        $legaility=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,$row)->getValue());




        $html="<tr>";
        $html.='<td><input name="c_name" value="'.$company_name.'"></td>';
        $html.='<td><input name="cp" value="'.$contact_person.'"></td>';
        $html.='<td><input name="email"  value="'.$email.'" id="mail_'.$nm.'" onClick="getStates(this.value);"></td>';
        $html.='<td>'.$location.'</td>';
        $html.='<td><input name="type" value="'.$type.'"></td>';
        $html.='<td><input name="sector" value="'.$sector.'"></td>';
        $html.='<td><input name="legal" value="'.$legaility.'"></td>';
        $html.='<td width="10"><div id="results_'.$nm.'">here'.$nm.'</div></td>';
        $html.='</form>';
        $html.="</tr>";


        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $chk_email= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `company` WHERE `email`='$email'") or die("didnt chk email");
        $chk_nm=mysqli_num_rows($chk_email);


        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == true) 
                {
                    if ($chk_nm == 1)
                        {
                            $redo= $redo+1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                    $ins_imp=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `company`(`ID`, `c_name`, `cp`, `email`, `status`, `location`, `Active`, `type`, `sector`, `legality`) VALUES
                        ('', '$company_name', '$contact_person', '$email', '', 'Ethiopia', 'active', '$type', '$sector', '$legaility')
                        ") or die("didnt enter data:".$email);
                    $html="";
                     }

                }
                else 
                {
                    echo '<script>$("results_'.$nm.'").html("error_log(message)")</script>';
                    echo 'error'.$nm;
                }

        $nm++;





    if ($row==$highestRow)
        { 
            if ($redo > 0)
                {
                echo "<br />There were ".$redo." records rejected becase they were already in the database.";
                }
        }



    }
}
```